# What about using Encapsulation to handle WCF service inheritance issues?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

This question is theoretical about programming and best practices in the context of *Microsoft WCF* with particular care to *Web Services*.

### Inheritance in web services

Consider a situation when we have some functionalities to be defined. We want to expose these functionalities to the world using web services. The functionalities are modeled by interfaces (which is a very good practice when dealing with distributes systems and so on). So we have something like the following:

```
///
/// Functionalities for a certain context, calling them A functionalities
///
public interface IFunctionalitiesA {
   FunctionalityA1ResMsg FunctionalityA1(FunctionalityA1ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityA2ResMsg FunctionalityA2(FunctionalityA2ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityA3ResMsg FunctionalityA3(FunctionalityA3ReqMsg msg);
}

///
/// Functionalities for a certain context, calling them B functionalities
///
public interface IFunctionalitiesB {
   FunctionalityB1ResMsg FunctionalityB1(FunctionalityB1ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityB2ResMsg FunctionalityB2(FunctionalityB2ReqMsg msg);
}

///
/// Functionalities for a certain context, calling them C functionalities
///
public interface IFunctionalitiesC {
   FunctionalityC1ResMsg FunctionalityC1(FunctionalityC1ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityC2ResMsg FunctionalityC2(FunctionalityC2ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityC3ResMsg FunctionalityC3(FunctionalityC3ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityC4ResMsg FunctionalityC4(FunctionalityC4ReqMsg msg);
}

///
/// Functionalities for a certain context, calling them D functionalities
///
public interface IFunctionalitiesD {
   FunctionalityD1ResMsg FunctionalityD1(FunctionalityD1ReqMsg msg);
   FunctionalityD2ResMsg FunctionalityD2(FunctionalityD2ReqMsg msg);
}
```

Now let us consider that all these functionalities can be implemented by some services. But it is not mandatory to have a service to implement them all. A service can implement some of them and another service can implement another subset of those. In particular I am asking to consider the following situation:

```
///
/// This service implements functionalities A and B.
///
public class ServiceS1 : IFunctionalitiesA, IFunctionalitiesB {
   ... /* Implementing interfaces methods */
}

///
/// This service implements functionalities C and D.
///
public class ServiceS2 : IFunctionalitiesC, IFunctionalitiesD {
   ... /* Implementing interfaces methods */
}
```

In particular please note that these two services will create, internally, some important stuff. I mean that they have resources that only them can access, for example the first service might keep an array of elements and so does the second. In few words, they are not dummy services, they have a state and resources and they are protected from external access (so they are declared as `public` or `protected`).

Now let us consider that we want to implement a service, maybe to be run on a different station, that implements all functionalities. This service will behave exactly like the two presented above when dealing with the respective implemented methods. Unfortunately we cannot derive from both of them. So we need to do this:

```
public class GlobalService : 
   IFunctionalitiesA, IFunctionalitiesB, IFunctionalitiesC, IFunctionalitiesD {
   ...
}
```

### Encapsulation... can it be the answer?

The question is:

> How to reuse the logic inside the two services implementing a subset
>   of the overall functionalities?

I ended up thinking about doing something like this:

```
public class GlobalService : 
   IFunctionalitiesA, IFunctionalitiesB, IFunctionalitiesC, IFunctionalitiesD {

   ///
   /// Encapsulating ServiceS1
   ///
   protected ServiceS1 srvs1;

   ///
   /// Encapsulating ServiceS2
   ///
   protected ServiceS2 srvs2;

   public GlobalService() {
      this.srvs1 = new ServiceS1();
      this.srvc2 = new ServiceS2();
   }

   ///
   /// Methods are redirected internally to the reused implementation
   /// This is to be done for all methods
   ///
   public FunctionalityA1ResMsg FunctionalityA1(FunctionalityA1ReqMsg msg) {
      return thissrvs1.FunctionalityA1(msg);
   }

   ...

}
```

By doing so I can reuse the implemented logic without creating redundant code again and again. Of course this can be an approach limited to some cases, but in these conditions (not so restrictive after all).

Is this a good approach to solve the problem? Do you think differently?